# Using R and paws: How to set credentials using profile in config file?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, credentials, profile, r-paws

I use SSO and a profile as defined in ~/.aws/config (MacOS) to access AWS services, for instance:

`aws s3 ls --profile myprofilename`

I would like to access AWS services from within R, using the paws() package. In order to do this, I need to set my credentials in the R code. I want to do this through accessing the profile in the ~/.aws/config file (as opposed to listing access keys in the code), but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

I looked at the extensive documentation [here](https://github.com/paws-r/paws/blob/main/docs/credentials.md#reference), but it doesn't seem to cover my use case.

The best I've been able to come up with is:

```
x = s3(config = list(credentials = list(profile = "myprofilename")))
x$list_objects()
```

... which throws an error: "Error in f(): No credentials provided", suggesting that the first line of code above does not connect to my profile as stored in ~/.aws/config.

Comment: You may need to use R packages that actually support the SSO authentication to AWS. Ours (i.e. [tiledb](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=tiledb)) does as far as I know (as we recently added SSO support from the AWS SDK), but I have only ever tried it with the pair of environment variables (_i.e._ non-SSO) myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have AWS cli credentials set up as a bash profile eg. `~/.aws/config`:

```
[profile myprof]
region=eu-west-2
output=json
```

.. and credentials eg. `~/.aws/credentials`:

```
[myprof]
aws_access_key_id = XXX
aws_secret_access_key = xxx
```

.. paws will use these if you add a line to `~/.Renviron`:

```
AWS_PROFILE=myprof
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to [generate a user/key with programmatic access to your S3 data](https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/connecting-to-aws-s3-with-r/). Then, assuming that `~/.aws/env` contains the values of the generated key:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=abc
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=123
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
```

insert the following line at the beginning of your file:

```
readRenviron("~/.aws/env")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. My AWS config file doesn't contain any keys because I use SSO, it only lists things like sso_account_id and sso_role_name. Also, readRenviron throws an error: File /.../.aws/config contains invalid line(s) (...) They were ignored".

Comment: Mmm this is anwser is not going to work then... I supposed you were storing the environment variables there, but I guess that the file contains the configurations of SSO.

Comment: I have modified the answer to remark that this is an alternative to SSO.

Comment: @Gorka I have the same problem except my .aws folder contains the files "credentials" and "config" where I store my keys. I would've thought that the paws package would read that but does not. Am I therefore bound to use environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/aws-single-sign-on-now-enables-command-line-interface-access-for-aws-accounts-using-corporate-credentials/) AWS blog provides details about how to get the temporary credentials for programatic access. If you can get the credentials and set the appropriate [environment variables](https://github.com/paws-r/paws/blob/main/docs/credentials.md#environment-variables), then the code should work fine without the profile name.

Or You can also try the following if you can get temporary credentials using `aws cli`

- Check if you can generate temporary credentials
  `aws sts assume-role --role-arn <value> --role-session-name <some-meaningful-session-name> --profile myprofilename`
- If you can execute the above successfully, then you can use [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sourcing-external.html) method to automate the process of generating credentials before your code runs.
- Put the above command in a bash script `get-temp-credentials.sh` and generate a JSON containing the temporary credentials as per the documentation.
- Add a new profile `programmatic-access` in the `~/.aws/config`

> ```
> [profile programmatic-access]
> credential_process = "/path/to/get-temp-credentials.sh"
> ```

- Finally update the code to use the profile name as `programmatic-access`