# How do I connect to AWS Athena in R using paws via the CLI v2 sso?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, r-paws

I am using AWS CLI v2 to create a configuration file and login to AWS via sso on my computer.  I am then trying to access the data stored in our database on AWS Athena through R using the paws package.

I think I have the configuration file setup correctly, but when I try to list the data catalogs in Athena, I get an error message: "Error loading SSO Token: Token for myprof does not exist"

In AWS CLI v2 (on Windows), I run `aws configure sso` and setup my config file as described in the [AWS documentation on configuring SSO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-token.html).

After doing that, my config file looks like this:

```
[profile myprof]
sso_session = myprof
sso_account_id = 123456789012
sso_role_name = AWSAdministratorAccess
region = us-east-2
output = json
[sso-session myprof]
sso_start_url = https://mycompany.awsapps.com/start#/
sso_region = us-east-2
sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access
```

In the process, my web browser opens up and I confirm the code that is shown in the command line.

In R, I have this code, as described in the paws documentation on [Using AWS Single Sign On](https://www.paws-r-sdk.com/developer_guide/credentials/#use-aws-single-sign-on-sso) and [connecting to Athena](https://www.paws-r-sdk.com/docs/athena/):

```
library(paws)
Sys.setenv(AWS_PROFILE = 'myprof',AWS_REGION = 'us-east-2')
svc = athena()
svc$list_data_catalogs(options("paws.log_level" = 3L))
```

When I run this, I get this result:

```
INFO [2023-11-10 08:20:45.468]: Unable to locate credentials file
Error: Error loading SSO Token: Token for myprof does not exist
```

From what I can understand from the paws documentation, I don't need a credentials file if I am using sso (unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221164/using-r-and-paws-how-to-set-credentials-using-profile-in-config-file)).  Wondering if there is something I am doing wrong, or if there is a setting I need to check to get this to work?  Not sure if the problem is in something I am doing, or with paws or the IAM settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was in my system environment settings.

I used the `traceback()` function to see where the `Error: Error loading SSO Token: Token for myprof does not exist` was coming from, and then found that it was coming from the `sso_credential_process` function in `paws`.  I was able to find the details of that function [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/paws.common/src/R/credential_providers.R).

That function references the system environment variables `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`.  Mine were not set correctly to direct the function to the sso cache, hence it not finding the credentials.  Once I updated those using `Sys.setenv(HOMEDRIVE = 'C:',HOMEPATH = 'Users/MYPROF')`, everything started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When using SSO you need to get your temporary credentials using aws cli.

```
aws sso login --profile myprof
```

Note: this is similar to how boto3 works: [How to use the AWS Python SDK while connecting via SSO credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311866/how-to-use-the-aws-python-sdk-while-connecting-via-sso-credentials)

```r
library(paws)

client <- athena(config(credentials(profile = "myprof")))
client$list_data_catalogs()
```

Note: you don't need to set environmental variables as you have set up your `.aws/config` file. You can simply set the profile in the athena connection.

Alternatively you could use [noctua](https://github.com/DyfanJones/noctua) which is built onto of `paws` to give a DBI interface.

```r
library(DBI)
library(noctua)

con <- dbConnect(noctua::athena(), profile_name = "myprof", s3_staging_dir = "s3://mybucket/athena-query")

dbListTables(con)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this, and linking that other related question.  I did run `aws sso login --profile myprof`, which created the sso cache like that other post mentioned.  Unfortunately, I still get the same error.  I also tried using noctua as you mentioned, and also got the same error.  Makes me think the issue is with my IAM setup, or paws.